# How to create your own asynchronous methods with async and await

Tags: c#, async-await

I've been trying to find a solution for quite a long time that would show me how to create Asynchronous methods that do not use existing asynchronous code. IE someClass.ActionAsync()
I basically have been wanting to do something like

```
public string GetParsedData(string code){
    Console.WriteLine("Starting parser");
    var result = "";
    foreach(var x in code.Split('\n')){
          result += Encode(x);
    }

    return result;

}
```

So I understand I must return a Task, but I have found no information on how to await a lambda expression or any other advice on how to break this down. Oddly I think I found the answer from re-sharper giving me dated advice which I will post below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mandatory read that explains **the root of all this discussion** much better is Microsoft's "[Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957)", including examples which help to learn it the "good way". The following summary is grabbed from there:

I was also newbie to this, but **in summary** what I have learned is that you need to distinguish between of IO-work vs. CPU-work. I was greatly inspired from @Stephen Cleary comment above.

- For **IO-bound** intensive work you already have external `xxxxAsync()` functions available in .NET which is preferred mechanism by Microsoft. If your code includes calls to external `await xxxxAsync()`, **then your function can be regarded as `async` as well**. In this way, while the CPU is idle waiting for IO, the calling thread is not blocked.
- For **CPU-bound** intensive work, without any external available `xxxxAsync()` function to call, there is an existing wrapper available in .NET to call your code: `Task.Factory.StartNew(NET-4.0)` or even easier and better `Task.Run(NET-4.5)`, the latter being preferred by Microsoft in this case (*). If your code includes calls to `await Task` or returns a `Task`, **then your function can be regarded as `async` as well**. In this way, while the intensive task runs in the ThreadPool, the calling thread is not blocked.

(*) This mechanism is NOT thought to create *async wrappers to your CPU-intensive functions*. And specially NEVER do this if you are creating a library. Instead, its the other way around: you should call the existing *sync CPU-intensive function* from your code by using Task.Run.

Now the **best example** I have found for the WEB-UI thread blocked by a CPU-intensive operation is [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html). You can directly go there and skip the theory part.

Answer (score 0):

So Resharper advised me to use TaskEx.Run (which is deprecated) and the proper answer appears to be Task.Run. I've found success rewriting the method as such,

```
public async Task<string> GetParsedData(string code){
    Console.WriteLine("Starting parser");
    var taskResult = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var result = "";
        foreach(var x in code.Split('\n'))
        {
            result += Encode(x);
        }

        return result;
    });
    return taskResult;
}
```

Now I can use the await keyword on this method within other async methods as needed.

Comment: This is actually a popular anti-patern: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Comment: @Noseratio and others, still quite new to the async-await and asynchronous programming in general so your responses are very appreciated. I can appreciate the danger of running into the golden hammer rule. My issue originally was trying to initialize SQLite databases on android in the background (not blocking). The database class would have a flag that indicated if it was unloaded, loading, or loaded, that would prevent the app from trying to read from it while loading or unloaded. Not sure if the scenario is a bit better for this pattern or not.

Comment: Christopher, you may want to post this as a separate question. Ideally, you should be using naturally asynchronous SQL APIs, instead of wrapping the synchronous ones with `Task.Run`. More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/20/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta.aspx

Comment: @ChristopherRichmond: I have a [four-part series on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) that discusses proper usage of `Task.Run`. In summary: if the work is I/O-bound (e.g., SQLite), then there should be async methods you can call, and if the code wraps the blocking methods in a `Task.Run`, then it is using `Task.Run` for the wrong thing. If the work is CPU-bound (e.g., your sample code), then `Task.Run` should be used to *invoke* the method, not *implement* the method.